oauth2 authorization server without form login
I would like to have the authentication server handle user authentication without requiring login form input. In oauth2 authorization server version 0.3.1, it was processed through customAuthenticationEntryPoint(), but after changing to version 1.2.3, user authentication is not processed.
When requesting http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=hts-client-id&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8081,
the result i want is http://127.0.0.1:8081/?code=alwdijnzldjiwilajiwdj (without form login)
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
import io.oauth2.autorizationserver.oauth2.repository.RegisteredClientJpaRepository;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.AuthorizationServerSettings;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.settings.ClientSettings;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.AuthorizationGrantType;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClientAuthenticationMethod;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.OidcScopes;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClientRepository;

import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;

import org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.MediaTypeRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {
private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
private final RegisteredClientJpaRepository registeredClientEntityRepository;

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        List<String> originUris = List.of("http://127.0.0.1:8081", "http://localhost:8080");
        originUris.forEach(config::addAllowedOrigin);
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    
        return source;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());
    
        http
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                customAuthenticationEntryPoint(),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.ALL))
                )
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
                        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .headers(headers -> headers
                .referrerPolicy(referrerPolicy -> referrerPolicy
                        .policy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.NO_REFERRER_WHEN_DOWNGRADE)
                )
        )
                ;
    
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        log.info("Custom AuthenticationEntryPoint");
        return (request, response, authException) -> {
            Authentication authentication = getAuthenticationFromUserDetailService();
    
            if (authentication != null) {
                log.info("Authenticated as user: {}", authentication.getName());
                log.info("Authenticated as user: {}", authentication.getPrincipal().toString());
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    
                response.sendRedirect("/oauth2/authorization/code");
                
    
            } else {
                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login");
            }
        };
    }
    
    private Authentication getAuthenticationFromUserDetailService() {
    
        log.info("Get Authentication from UserDetailService");
    
        try {
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername("user");
            log.info("userDetails : {}", userDetails);
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
    
    
    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error retrieving user details: {}", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings providerSettings() {
    
        return AuthorizationServerSettings
                .builder()
                .issuer("http://localhost:8080")
                .build();
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
    
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("hts-client-id")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8081")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(false).build())
                .build();
        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        RSAKey rsaKey = generateRsa();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }
    
    private RSAKey generateRsa() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey).privateKey(privateKey).keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).build();
    }
    
    private KeyPair generateRsaKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        //UserDetails user = User.withUsername("user").password("{noop}1234").authorities("ROLE_USER").build();
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("{noop}1234")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeHttpRequests) -> authorizeHttpRequests
                        .requestMatchers("/oauth2/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/h2-console").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                //.formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
                .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                ;
        return http.build();
     }

}

